# timeout pipeline

Tags: shell, command-line, signals, timeout

I want to execute these two timeout command on the same command but with a different time and instructions. So

```
timeout --signal=SIGINT 5s command 
timeout --signal=SIGKILL 10s command
```

How to append them in one line?

Comment: `timeout --signal=SIGKILL 10s { timeout --signal=SIGINT 5s command ; }` or `timeout --signal=SIGKILL 10s bash -c 'timeout --signal=SIGINT 5s command'` ?

Comment: I don't understand what "in one line" is supposed to mean as `cmd1 ; cmd2` is probably not what you are looking for. If you need this structure often and want to reduce code then you can write a function which calls its parameter like the two example lines.

Comment: no, I want if the first signal doesn`t work(in my command that is exactly the case) to kill it with the second signal(it works)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
timeout --signal=SIGKILL 10s timeout --kill-after=5 --signal=SIGINT 5s command
```